# How to permanently hide Debug Console in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have looked for a solution but couldn't find one, recently I switched the Explorer in VSCode from the LHS to the RHS and it works better, the problem I am now having is that when I open the terminal I get a debug console on the left - see picture below.

Is there a way in which I can disable/hide the Debug Console part of the terminal?  It is always maximized when I start a new console and I can't set it to minimize.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Either choose `Reset Location` in the context menu or just drag the `Debug Console` header back into the upper part of the Panel (like to the right or left of the `Terminal` header).

At some point you must have dragged the `Debug Console` header into the body of the `Terminal` (when `Terminal` was active and into the left half of its view).

You'll also notice that the option to `Hide 'Debug Console'` is disabled in your first situation - that is a hint of sorts - it is actually **within** the `Terminal` view and so cannot be separately hidden from its context menu.

Comment: it works by just D&D to left. thanks.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Click on the debug tab and drag it to the top.